# What is meant by 'separate, isolate, or modify the audio or visual components' in YouTube's API Terms of Service?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to learn more about YouTube's TOS. More specifically:

> II. Prohibitions
>
> 8: separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;

I'm working inside of a Google Chrome Extension which consists of a persistant background page and a foreground pop-up page. I would like to display audiovisual content in the foreground to users. This is fine and works, however, upon closing the foreground -- the audiovisual content ceases because the page has been destroyed.

As such, I would like to sync two YouTube players such that one in the background is unmuted with the one in the foreground being muted, but with its visual content sync'ed to that of the background. Would this violate YouTube's TOS? I'm hoping the answer is no - it seems akin to having a tab open. Sometimes the visual content can be seen (at the user's discretion) but the audio content would be uninterrupted.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret that correctly:

- "to separate or isolate" means to cut off the video or the audio part (or even different channels of it, if any) of the returned/streamed media
- "to modify" means that you transform the data in some way and you display it to the user, instead of the original data (i. e. you are prohibited to make a video streaming application that displays every movie in black and white).

So, unfortunately, I think your requirement does indeeed violate the TOS.

Comment: Is there no distinction for physically ripping the audio from the video? I know that the separate/isolate clause was used against youtube-mp3.org. This is clear to me -- the audio is being ripped away from the video. I've left the data fully intact and only interact with the player through the YouTube APIs. Do you know if there's a way for me to get in touch with a more definitive source?

Comment: @SeanAnderson Contact YouTube directly - but I'd say that presenting stuff to the user that's different from that in the wire does count as violation.

Comment: Following the YouTube's Contact Us led me to 'Are you a Developer?' After clicking that it said, for developers with questions -- go to StackOverflow. :/ Perhaps they don't have a public email and I need to write them.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Oh what the heck... That's quite unprofessional, so to say! Well, isn't there a generic "support email"?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/SE6EJOz.png This is all I've been able to locate so far. Perhaps I'm being idiotic, but I think they're making it pretty tricky to contact them directly, in usual Google fashion. :)

Comment: @SeanAnderson Yeah, Google is wrapped in a big scary dark case... I think you'll actually need to write them a letter.

Comment: I'm gonna do that this evening. I'll update this post with any responses I receive. Thanks mate have a good one. :)

Answer (score 0):

In short: 
There's no way for you to make an app that allows you to listen to a youtube song with your display off...

(I believe they want you to see the ads or they want to prove to those who pay them to put the ads that people sees the ads they put on all youtube videos).